# multi dimensional array from single array

Tags: php

i need make multidimensional array from a single  array loop, the value of array will like color size material and others, and child will red, orange

EX:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [option_value_id] => 46
            [option_id] => 11
            [image] => 
            [sort_order] => 2
            [language_id] => 1
            [name] => Size
            [type] => select
            [option_value_name] => Small
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [option_value_id] => 50
            [option_id] => 13
            [image] => 
            [sort_order] => 1
            [language_id] => 1
            [name] => color
            [type] => image
            [option_value_name] => Black
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [option_value_id] => 48
            [option_id] => 11
            [image] => 
            [sort_order] => 2
            [language_id] => 1
            [name] => Size
            [type] => select
            [option_value_name] => Large
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [option_value_id] => 50
            [option_id] => 13
            [image] => 
            [sort_order] => 1
            [language_id] => 1
            [name] => color
            [type] => image
            [option_value_name] => Black
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [option_value_id] => 47
            [option_id] => 11
            [image] => 
            [sort_order] => 2
            [language_id] => 1
            [name] => Size
            [type] => select
            [option_value_name] => Medium
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [option_value_id] => 50
            [option_id] => 13
            [image] => 
            [sort_order] => 1
            [language_id] => 1
            [name] => color
            [type] => image
            [option_value_name] => Black
        )

)
```

this is the array i get i need make to this format

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_option_value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [option_value_id] => 50
                            [name] => Black
                        )
                )

            [option_id] => 13
            [name] => color
            [type] => image
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_option_value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [option_value_id] => 46
                            [name] => Small
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [option_value_id] => 47
                            [name] => Medium
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [option_value_id] => 48
                            [name] => Large

                        )

                )

            [option_id] => 11
            [name] => Size
            [type] => select
        )

)
```

Comment: does this data come from a database? As PDO has grouping fetch methods..  more or less like -> `$pdo->query('SELECT product_option_value, <other_columns> FROM t')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);`

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all to get your desired result?

Comment: yas the data from database but my data keep as multi option in array format,
EX: option_value_id = 45,46,50  SKU = PINK_M_OPTION3,
this i explode  option value id to array then select from option value table